# VS Visual GDB intellisense not finding library, but compiles properly

Tags: c, visual-studio, sqlite, gdb

In particular, #include "sqlite3.h" gives an error [Clang Intellisense] Error: 'sqlite3.h' file not found in Visual Studio.

Everything works fine when compiling/running, but the intellisense errors are annoying.

I've installed sqlite3-dev and ran updates/upgrades. 
I see sqlite3.h in the usr/include directory which is included in the list of intellisense directories under project properties.
sqlite3 is included in the Library names (Makefile settings -> Config settings)

Is my path going to the wrong library or am I just missing something simple? I don't see the sqlite.c file in there and looking the the .h file, I don't see the functions I am using (from an example) like SQLITE_OK or sqlite3_free.

Again, everything works, it's just the intellisense that doesn't work. At least from what I can tell so far.

Oh, and the code is running on raspbian if that matters.

Comment: is this a compile problem or a runtime problem?   or is this a visual-studio problem?  If it is a compile or runtime problem, then Please post the code.

Comment: Guessing it a VS issue. The code runs fine, it's just intellisense that has an issue.Same issue on 2 different machines and only with the 1 lib.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I experience the same the first time I open the solution. But I managed to get rid of it by opening one of the included header files and a clean Rebuild. 
my VS version is 2015